# Xpages get component value in extlib dialog box

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I defined a document datasource(called document1) in a panel in my extlib dialog box.  Within this panel, it contains dialog content and dialog butotn bar.  Within the dialog content, in contains a custom control that has all the components likes dojo edit box, list box, radio butotn etc.  Within the dialog button bar, it contains a Save button.  On save, I could not get the value from any component by the following getComponent, document.getDocument.getxxx:

```
 print (getComponent.getValue("control"));
 print (document1.getDocument(true).getValueInString("control"));
 print (document1.getValue("control"));
```

Interesting to do know that document1.sertValue("control", newvalue) and document1.getDocument(true).isNewNote() are all working.

The dialog box is opened from a view column in the repeat.  All data are shown in dialog box corerctly.  I could save the modified data, retrieve them and display them with no issue.  The only thing that i could not get their values for processing.

The Save event handler is full update with set partial execution mode for the panel

panel is ignore its parameter and set scope to request but no luck.

Your help is really appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually document1.getDocument().getXXX('name of the item') and document1.getValue("name of the item") their parameter shoud be name of the item, not contorl id !!!  They are workable :-).  However, still no luck in getComponent.getValue("control").

Comment: shouldn't "print (getComponent.getValue("control"));" be "print (getComponent("control").getValue();" instead?

Comment: Ah, you're right, Frantisek. It's getComponent("control").getValue() :-)

Comment: Sorry I mistyed it.  I actually did getComponent('controlId').getValue() and try again but still no luck.  Just wonder that is it because of control in extlib dialog box.

Comment: I just found that getComponent('controlId').getValue() is not working for extlib control, that is <xe:djTextBox>

Comment: This is also happending for core control <xp:inputText>.  The main reason because both are in custom control and their values are bind to compositeData.document1.fieldName !!!   So how to get value from componnet which has its data bind to compositeData?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you need to consider and/or check:

- make sure you actually got hands on that control. Since it is inside a custom control you easily could have more than one of them. In this case you either need your own function `getComponentChild(parentName,controlName) or (IMHO better) you read it from the compositeData of the customControl (which is a MAP)`
- when you bind a control, it is esier to go after its binding than to use `getValue()`. So when you bind to `document.subject`, look for that value (or `viewScope.someValue` if you bound it to the viewScope)
- if  validation fails in the submission or you query at an earlier phase, you can't use `getValue()` but need to use getSubmittedValue() since that contains the raw value before validation happened

Let us know how it goes